# Linkify text in android

Tags: android

i am using following code in my app:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LinkifyDemo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView linkify = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.linkify);
        linkify.setText("http://www.google.com");
        Linkify.addLinks(linkify, Linkify.WEB_URLS);


        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

also included followin permission in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But application giving error,getting force close.
Can any one help me in this.
Thanks!!

Comment: Also, attaching the error is about the best thing you can do when the question contains "application is giving an error."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call `findViewById()` before calling `setContentView()`. Make the `setContentView` invocation the first thing after the `super` call.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you get any exceptions, you should post the logcat to make your question easier to resolve.

And then, you're calling `findViewById()` before `setContentView()`, this will always give you an error.